# Setting width to span using JavsScript not working

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to dynamically change width of a span based on the content of the span, So my app has a lot of span row-wise and the use modify content of the spans. On change of content I am trying to uniform the width of each span to be equal to the maxWidth of all the spans combined.

i.e `spanWidths = [ '50px', '34px', '56px', '87px' ]`

I need to convert all these spans into -> `[ '87px', '87px', '87px', '87px' ]`

[image]

The box model for the span :

[image]

As you can see the width is set to `87px` on the span yet, on inspecting it is weirdly `57.98px` which is inclusive of the border, padding and content.

The css for the span : (I am using `box-sizing: border-box` throughout)

```
.annotation-speaker {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(224, 239, 241, 0.5);
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px 5px 6px 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am confused as to how should I be calculating the `spanWidths` array having the widths of all the spans after on modifies the content in the span.

This is what I am currently doing :

```
const css = getComputedStyle($speakerBox); // $speakerBox is my span
const r = $speakerBox.getBoundingClientRect();

const w = $speakerBox.scrollWidth + parseInt(css.paddingLeft) + parseInt(css.paddingRight);

maxSpeakerTagWidth = Math.max(maxSpeakerTagWidth, w);
```

Here `r.width` and `$speakerBox.scrollWidth` are different too! Am confused as to which one should I even consider!

And to make all span's the same width as `maxSpeakerTagWidth` :

```
$speakerBox.style.width = maxSpeakerTagWidth + 'px';
```

This isn't working though!

Comment: Why don't you use css table layout for such scenario. You won't need to calculate widths in JS. Just use display  table > table-row > table-cell structure to get equal widths  on each span. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table

Comment: I need be changing widths when the content changes ...

Comment: That's what above css display:table exactly does. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table

Comment: Think your row as a table row and apply css. You can read this article. No need to calculate widths using JS. Just use css. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/table-layout/

Comment: Span is an inline element, therefore you need to apply style="display: block" to it in order to have the width set

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a bit on JSFiddle (:P), seem to have found myself a solution, but am still not able to see it work on my project, but work's just fine on JSFiddle!

https://jsfiddle.net/a5kurstv/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .spanBox {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 25px;
        background-color: rgb(224, 239, 241, 0.5);
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0px 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.7px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 1em;
        box-sizing: content-box;
      }

      .input {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 1em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Just type in the input box press enter -->

    <span id="span1" class="spanBox">gg</span>
    <span id="span2" class="spanBox">gg</span>
    <span id="span3" class="spanBox">gg</span>
    <span id="span4" class="spanBox">gg</span>
    <span id="span5" class="spanBox">gg</span>

    <input onkeypress="change(event)" class="input" />
  </body>
  <script>
     let maxW = -1;
     const change = (e) => {
       if(e.keyCode === 13) {
          const val = e.target.value;

          const $span1 = document.getElementById('span1');

          $span1.textContent = `${val}`;

          calcMax();
       }
     }

     const calcMax = () => {
        maxW = -1;
        for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            const $span = document.getElementById(`span${i}`);

            if($span.style.width === '') {
              const r = $span.getBoundingClientRect();

              maxW = Math.max(maxW, r.width);
            }
            else {
              $span.style.width = '1px';

              maxW = Math.max(maxW, $span.scrollWidth);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(() => update(), 100);
     }

     const update = () => {
       console.log("MAX ", maxW);

       for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
           const $span = document.getElementById(`span${i}`);

           $span.style.width = maxW + 'px';
       }
     }

     calcMax();

  </script>
<html>
```